# How do I join six list of tuples into a pandas dataframe using the first value of each tuple as the key?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I'm testing out a service that has an api that can pull parsed 10K corporate data from.  For each metric pulled (EBIT, cash, totalassets, etc) I store the quarterly date and the metric inside a tuple and each tuple inside a list.  The results are six lists of 43 - 80 tuples.  I would like a dataframe with a column for the corporate ticker, date, and metrics.  How do I turn what I have (lists of tuples) into that?

Code below to pull the data (this is example so no charge):

```
import numpy as np
import json
import pandas as pd

content = requests.get(r'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX')

ebit_list = []
date_list = []
totalassets_list = []
cash_list = []
totalCurrentAssets_list = []
totalCurrentLiabilities_list = []


for i in content.json()['Financials']['Income_Statement']['quarterly']:

    try:
        ebit_list.append((i, float(content.json()['Financials']['Income_Statement']['quarterly'][i]['ebit'])))
    except:
        pass

    try:
        date_list.append(i)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        totalassets_list.append((i, float(content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly'][i]['totalAssets'])))
    except:
        pass



for i in content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly']:
    #print(i, float(content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly']['2019-12-28']['totalCurrentLiabilities']))
    try:
        cash_list.append((i, float(content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly'][i]['cash'])))
    except:
        pass

    try:
        totalCurrentAssets_list.append((i, float(content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly'][i]['totalCurrentAssets'])))
    except:
        pass

    try:
        totalCurrentLiabilities_list.append((i, float(content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly'][i]['totalCurrentLiabilities'])))
    except:
        pass
```

I would like a dataframe with all dates (meaning if a metric is missing, a zero is filled in) and following columns:

`date`, `ebit`, `totalassets`, `cash`, `totalCurrentAssets`, `totalCurrentLiabilities`

I'm not sure how to extract tuples and values inside each tuple though.

Comment: What is `ticker`?

Comment: oops.  Ticker is suppose to be a US stock ticker.  Ignore that.  i'll figure out how to get that later.  I will edit and take that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function in `pandas.Series` to match the dates with the data you need. This will insert `NaN` for cells that have no matching values which will make it easier to deal with missing data later. If you still want to fill zeros, you can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
# Create a dataframe using date
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_list})

# To avoid the code getting messy in the next steps
stuff = {'ebit': ebit_list, 'totalassets': totalassets_list, 'cash': cash_list, 'totalCurrentAssets': totalCurrentAssets_list, 'totalCurrentLiabilities': totalCurrentLiabilities_list}

for name, values in stuff.items():
    value_dict = {t[0]: t[1] for t in values}   # t is each tuple in the list
    df[name] = df['date'].map(value_dict)       # map will match the correct date to the value 

# assuming you need the dataframe to be sorted by date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])         # we should use actual numbers instead of date string
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

# if you want to fill 0s to missing values
# df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

`ignore_index` argument in `sort_values` is to make sure the indices are not jumbled up after sorting. If your `pandas` version is old, it might give a `TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'` when sorting. If so you should use the following to reset indices instead

```
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

At the end this is the df

```
         date          ebit   totalassets          cash  totalCurrentAssets  totalCurrentLiabilities
0  2000-03-31           NaN  7.007000e+09           NaN                 NaN             1.853000e+09
1  2000-06-30           NaN  6.932000e+09           NaN                 NaN             1.873000e+09
2  2000-09-30           NaN  6.803000e+09           NaN                 NaN             1.933000e+09
3  2000-12-31  0.000000e+00  5.986000e+09           NaN                 NaN             1.637000e+09
4  2001-03-31  0.000000e+00  6.130000e+09           NaN                 NaN             1.795000e+09
..        ...           ...           ...           ...                 ...                      ...
75 2018-12-29  2.334600e+10  3.737190e+11  4.477100e+10        1.408280e+11             1.082830e+11
76 2019-03-30  1.341500e+10  3.419980e+11  3.798800e+10        1.233460e+11             9.377200e+10
77 2019-06-29  1.154400e+10  3.222390e+11  5.053000e+10        1.349730e+11             8.970400e+10
78 2019-09-28  1.562500e+10  3.385160e+11  4.884400e+10        1.628190e+11             1.057180e+11
79 2019-12-28  2.556900e+10  3.406180e+11  3.977100e+10        1.632310e+11             1.021610e+11
```

Comment: brilliant! And thank you for the great explanation in the comments.

Comment: Btw you can do `df[name] = df['date'].map(dict(values))` one liner instead of having two lines inside the for loop. I'm keeping the answer the same since it has more clarity that way.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your example to work, requests is undefined.

but here is some code that may do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd


def create_df(list_of_lists):
    pd.DataFrame({x[0]: pd.Series(x[1:]) for x in list of lists})
```

Comment: My bad.  I forgot to do import requests

Comment: Hello @ IjonTichy.  Thank you for replying.  I tried the above and the tuple is in each observation.  I was looking for the [1] value of each tuple to be the observation, joined by the [0] value which is the date and each column header having the name of the list the corresponding values came from.

Answer (score 1):

We can actually simplify this code quite a bit to get you the result you want (and make it easier to adjust in the future!)

The finished code is here, with more detailed explanations below:

```
import numpy as np
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

content = requests.get(r'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX')

income_data = content.json()['Financials']['Income_Statement']['quarterly']
income = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(income_data).transpose().set_index("date")
income = income[['ebit']]

balance_data = content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly']
balance = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(balance_data).transpose().set_index("date")
balance = balance[['totalAssets', 'cash', 'totalCurrentAssets', 'totalCurrentLiabilities']]

financials = income.merge(balance, left_index = True, right_index = True).fillna(0)
```

The financials DataFrame will look like this (only showing data from 2005-2009):

```
| date       |      ebit |   totalAssets |       cash |   totalCurrentAssets |   totalCurrentLiabilities |
|:-----------|----------:|--------------:|-----------:|---------------------:|--------------------------:|
| 2009-12-26 | 4.758e+09 |    5.3926e+10 | 7.609e+09  |           3.3332e+10 |                1.3097e+10 |
| 2009-09-26 | 0         |    4.7501e+10 | 5.263e+09  |           3.1555e+10 |                1.1506e+10 |
| 2009-06-27 | 1.732e+09 |    4.814e+10  | 5.605e+09  |           3.517e+10  |                1.6661e+10 |
| 2009-03-31 | 0         |    4.3237e+10 | 4.466e+09  |           0          |                1.3751e+10 |
| 2008-12-31 | 0         |    4.2787e+10 | 7.236e+09  |           0          |                1.4757e+10 |
| 2008-09-30 | 0         |    3.9572e+10 | 1.1875e+10 |           0          |                1.4092e+10 |
| 2008-06-30 | 0         |    3.1709e+10 | 9.373e+09  |           0          |                9.218e+09  |
| 2008-03-31 | 0         |    3.0471e+10 | 9.07e+09   |           0          |                9.634e+09  |
| 2007-12-31 | 0         |    3.0039e+10 | 9.162e+09  |           0          |                1.0535e+10 |
| 2007-09-30 | 0         |    2.5347e+10 | 9.352e+09  |           0          |                9.299e+09  |
| 2007-06-30 | 0         |    2.1647e+10 | 7.118e+09  |           0          |                6.992e+09  |
| 2007-03-31 | 0         |    1.8711e+10 | 7.095e+09  |           0          |                5.485e+09  |
| 2006-12-31 | 0         |    1.9461e+10 | 7.159e+09  |           0          |                7.337e+09  |
| 2006-09-30 | 0         |    1.7205e+10 | 6.392e+09  |           0          |                6.471e+09  |
| 2006-06-30 | 0         |    1.5114e+10 | 0          |           0          |                5.023e+09  |
| 2006-03-31 | 0         |    1.3911e+10 | 0          |           0          |                4.456e+09  |
| 2005-12-31 | 0         |    1.4181e+10 | 0          |           0          |                5.06e+09   |
| 2005-09-30 | 0         |    1.1551e+10 | 3.491e+09  |           0          |                3.484e+09  |
| 2005-06-30 | 0         |    1.0488e+10 | 0          |           0          |                3.123e+09  |
| 2005-03-31 | 0         |    1.0111e+10 | 0          |           0          |                3.352e+09  |
```

---

The result of `content.json()['Financials']['Income_Statement']['quarterly']` is a dictionary with each key being the date and each value being a second dictionary with the column data.

```
{'2005-03-31': {'date': '2005-03-31',
                'filing_date': None,
                'currency_symbol': 'USD',
                'researchDevelopment': '120000000.00',
                ...},
'2005-06-30': {...},
...}
```

Since this is the case, you can actually load that dictionary directly into a pandas dataframe by using

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(income_data).transpose().set_index("date")`

The transpose is necessary because of the structure of the JSON.  Pandas expects a dictionary formatted like `{'column name': data}`.  Since the keys are dates, you will initially get a DataFrame where the rows are labeled "totalAssets", "cash", etc. and the columns are dates.  the `transpose()` command flips the rows and columns so it's in the format you need.  *The final `.set_index("date")` command is there to use the "date" data instead of the initial key date, for consistency and to name the index.  It is completely optional*

Now, this DataFrame will have every column from the JSON file, but you are only interested in a few.  The code

`income = income[['ebit']]`

selects only the relevant columns from the data.

Since you are pulling data from two different sources, you do need to create two different tables.  This has an additional benefit that you can more clearly see which columns are being pulled in from the 'Income Statement' and which are from the 'Balance Sheet'.

The final line

`financials = income.merge(balance, left_index = True, right_index = True).fillna(0)`

merges the two tables together using their indexes (in this case, the "date" column).  `fillna(0)` ensures that any missing data is replaced by a zero value, as you requested.

If you end up needing to add another table, such as 'Cash_Flow', you would use the same lines of code to create the table and select the relevant columns, and add a second merge line:

```
cashflow_data = content.json()['Financials']['Balance_Sheet']['quarterly']
cashflow = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cashflow_data).transpose().set_index("date")
cashflow = cashflow[['accountsPayable', 'liabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity']]
...
financials.merge(cashflow, left_index = True, right_index = True).fillna(0)
```

---

As a bonus tip, there is quite a lot of data in your source JSON!  To see what columns are available to you in any given table, use the following:

`cashflow.columns.sort_values()`

to get an alphabetized list of the columns you can use:

```
      ['accountsPayable', 'accumulatedAmortization', 'accumulatedDepreciation',
       'accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome', 'additionalPaidInCapital',
       'capitalLeaseObligations', 'capitalSurpluse', 'cash',
       'cashAndShortTermInvestments', 'commonStock',
       'commonStockSharesOutstanding', 'commonStockTotalEquity',
       'currency_symbol', 'deferredLongTermAssetCharges',
       'deferredLongTermLiab', 'filing_date', 'goodWill', 'intangibleAssets',
       'inventory', 'liabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity', 'longTermDebt',
       'longTermDebtTotal', 'longTermInvestments', 'negativeGoodwill',
       'netReceivables', 'netTangibleAssets', 'nonCurrentAssetsTotal',
       'nonCurrentLiabilitiesOther', 'nonCurrentLiabilitiesTotal',
       'nonCurrrentAssetsOther', 'noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity',
       'otherAssets', 'otherCurrentAssets', 'otherCurrentLiab', 'otherLiab',
       'otherStockholderEquity', 'preferredStockRedeemable',
       'preferredStockTotalEquity', 'propertyPlantAndEquipmentGross',
       'propertyPlantEquipment', 'retainedEarnings',
       'retainedEarningsTotalEquity', 'shortLongTermDebt', 'shortTermDebt',
       'shortTermInvestments',
       'temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests', 'totalAssets',
       'totalCurrentAssets', 'totalCurrentLiabilities', 'totalLiab',
       'totalPermanentEquity', 'totalStockholderEquity', 'treasuryStock',
       'warrants']
```

This is also extremely helpful when there is a misspelling in the data, such as in "capitalSurpluse" above.